# do the ram lose what it remembers when the power if cut off?

Tags: computation-models

after shutting down the computer do the ram loses what it remember ? if yes is there some technics  that are used to get what is stocked into the ram after shutting down the computer ?

Comment: This is definitely not a question about [tag:computation-models], and I'm not sure it belongs on this site at all. Depending on your motivation it's either a security question (and related questions have been answered on security.stackexchange.com: [e.g.](//security.stackexchange.com/q/7299/20403)) or an electronics engineering question (although my reading of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic is that it's not on topic on electronics.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes 
 **RAM** chips remember things only while a computer is powered on, so they're used for storing whatever a computer is working on in the very short term.

In today's technology, random-access memory takes the form of integrated circuits. RAM is normally associated with volatile types of memory (such as DRAM modules), where stored information is lost if power is removed, although non-volatile RAM has also been developed.
[1] Other types of non-volatile memories exist that allow random access for read operations, but either do not allow write operations or have other kinds of limitations on them. These include most types of ROM and a type of flash memory called NOR-Flash.

for more information

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory
```

Comment: When I started in this game, computers still used [magnetic cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-core_memory) which did in fact retain their contents without power. (And which were as random to access as any DRAM.)

Answer (score 1):

The main bulk of DRAM is made up of capacitors storing a charge to store the bit. This needs to be refreshed regularly otherwise the capacitor will lose charge due to parasitic drain and [electromagnetic effects from accessing neighbouring rows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer).

When the power is cut the DRAM controller will no longer be refreshing rows so eventually all the capacitors will drain. If you cool the ram module down this will take longer. This property is used in the [cold boot attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack)